# Negrita en iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Estoy trabajando con itextsharp y llevo varias semanas buscando y probando el tema de poner negritas.

He probado con este código, por ejemplo:

```
Font verdanaBold = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 7f, Font.BOLD);
```

Me dice que falta un `using`, pero tengo puesto:

```
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.fonts;
```

Después con:

```
documento.Add(new Paragraph("TITULO 1",Text.BOLD);
```

Y tampoco me funcionó.

Os pongo una parte del código:

```
//CARACTERISTICAS CLIENTE
var MyFont1 = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 18);

//CARACTERISTICAS EMPRESA
var FontColour = new BaseColor(255, 0, 0);
var MyFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 11, FontColour, Font.BOLD);
```

Un parafo:

```
Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(" " + tb_direccion.Text + " ", MyFont1);
p2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
doc.Add(p2);
```

¿Alguna sugerencia para agregar negrilla?

Comment: ¿Con este código obtienes errores?, si es así, por favor, [edit] la pregunta para  incluir la descripción del error. Te puede interesar esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10213836/4092887).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ensayar de la siguiente forma:

```
var MyFont = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN, 11, Font.BOLD);
documento.Add(new Paragraph("TITULO 1", MyFont));
```

Comment: Con esto, en la parte de `Font.BOLD` me dice si falta algun `using`

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolví con el siguiente código:

```
private static Font SegoeBold
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            var fontName = "Segoe Bold";
            if (!FontFactory.IsRegistered(fontName))
            {
                var fontPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot") + "\\Fonts\\segoeui.ttf";
                FontFactory.Register(fontPath);
            }
            return FontFactory.GetFont(fontName, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, 9f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que hace es directamente buscar el archivo de la tipografía.
Incluso puedes descargar tipografías de internet y, sin necesidad de instalarlas, hacer algo muy parecido:

```
private static BaseFont _sourceSans = BaseFont.CreateFont(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.otf"), BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

private static Font StandardFont = new Font(_sourceSans, 9, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
```

Para colocar los textos, recuerda la siguiente jerarquía:

1. Chunk
2. Phrase
3. Paragraph

Un `Paragraph` está compuesto de `Phrase`s que a su vez están compuestas por `Chunk`s. Un ejemplo:

```
Phrase folio = new Phrase(new Chunk("Folio: ", SemiboldFont));
folio.Add(new Chunk("12345", StandardFont));
```

Como podrás observar, primero creé un objeto `Phrase` que contiene un `Chunk` con una tipografía "semibold", y después al mismo `Phrase` le añadí otro `Chunk` pero con la tipografía "estándar", así puedes crear párrafos con distintas tipografías. Con ello ya sólo hace falta colocarlo en el documento:

```
doc.Add(folio);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto utilizando esto:

```
        var MyFontBold = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 11);
```

Y luego para usarlas:

```
     PdfPCell titulomaquina = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + cb_maquina.Text + "", MyFontBold));
        titulomaquina.Colspan = 3;
        titulomaquina.Border = 0;
        titulomaquina.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
        table.AddCell(titulomaquina);
```